# Post render - How can I remove unwanted glow/haze?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, lighting, reflection

I use cycles to render my images (CPU). I also use 3 point studio lighting with 1000 watts of power and an overcast HDR. For some reason, while rendering my image looks fine but when the render finishes every light gets blown out and my reflections start glowing like crazy.

While rendering the image:

[image: its fine]

When the rendering is finished:

[image: and then]

My compositor setup:

[image: node]

After Lowered glow:

[image: finished result with suggestions]

New settings:

[image: new settings]

**Q:** How can I remove the unwanted glow/haze?

Comment: You have not shown your compositing Node tree, maybe you have added some glow node there.

Comment: Or a glare node.

Comment: Ive added the compositor screen shot. Do all of these effects get added last? also any suggestions on my compositor?

Comment: mute or delete the glare node.

Comment: Hi :). Yes, Compositor nodes are applied on top of a finished render. In your case, the Glare node is waay too strong - you might consider turning it down a bit.

Comment: I got that from a tutorial. Thank you all for helping me with my defaults. 2 weeks in over here so resources like these are amazing! Thank you all for existing. I hope to become helpful like you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because of the Glare node, you can reduce the glare by increasing the threshold value to some higher values if you want a very light and subtle glow effect,
and if you don't want any kind of Glow, simply delete the glare node, and everything will work fine.